# Alternative concept for late binding in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently learning Java, coming from PHP.
Now I'm a bit lost because I've just noted that it seems like there is nothing like the concept of late binding I'm used to use from PHP.

Does this mean, I cannot provide methods in a base class, which every child class can use with its own member values?
I mean, there must be concept for it, since it's hard to imagine, that you have to add such methods and functions to every single child class...

Let me give a concrete example, just in case it is not clear what I am wondering about.
How would I solve something like the following PHP structure in Java?

```php
abstract class BaseClass {
  protected String $value = 'Base';
    
  public function getValue(): String {
    return $this->value;
  }
}
    
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  protected String $value = 'Child';
}
    
$obj = new ChildClass();
print $obj->getValue();    // Shall print "Child"
```

Thank you very much for any hints/clarification.

Comment: You can't override fields, only methods.

Comment: What exactly makes this example “late static binding”? It looks like ordinary late binding to me.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I mixed up the terms, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the initialization in the constructor, you can initialize a field to different values based on the class.

```
public abstract class Base {
    String value;
    public Base() {
        value = "Base";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Child extends Base {
    public Child () {
        value = "Child";
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Base x = new Child();
        System.out.println(x.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Java` supports polymorphism as well. But not for the fields, but for methods.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        BaseClass obj = new ChildClass();
        System.out.println(obj.getValue()); // will print "Child"
    }

    public abstract static class BaseClass {

        public String getValue() {
            return "Base";
        }
    }

    public static class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "Child";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't override a field in Java. But you don't ever NEED to do this!

```
class Base {
  protected String field1 = "foo";
}

class ExtendedBase extends Base {
    public ExtendedBase() {
        this.field1 = "bar";
    }
}
```